# How to load more values in textfield using select option in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The current project I am working on needs to retrieve the data from the database.

I thought about using select option or dropdown in html , using javascript it will append or set the text in the text field, then values came from the database.

[CURRENT RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQi7i.jpg)

```js
    function PopulateUserName() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("iSupervisor");
        var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName");
        field.value = dropdown.value;
    }
```

```html
<?php
     include('connection_phpmyadmin.php');

            $result = $conn->query("select * from company_profile");
            echo '<form action ="func/schedule_add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            <label>SELECT COMPANY NAME </label>';
            echo '<select name="cp_id" id="iSupervisor" onchange="PopulateUserName()">';
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        unset($b_id, $company_name);
                        $cp_id = $row['cp_id'];
                        $company_name = $row['company_name'];
                        $company_code = $row['company_code'];
                            echo '
                                <option value="'.$cp_id.'">'.$company_name.'</option>'; 
                            
                }
                            echo '</select>';
                            echo '   <input id="iSupervisorUserName" name="OBKey_WF_Manger_Supervisor_1" type="text" />';
                            echo " </form>";
?>
```

My table consist of cols

- cp_id
- company_name
- company_add
- date_added

[Can you please help me to view  company_add and date added in input text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I918H.jpg)

Comment: **what you looking for is dependent select dropdown**. load the companies on the first dropdown, then use jquery `onchange()` event when there's a change on the first dropdown, then you will need to use ajax to fetch results for the second one, then repeat.

Comment: I've done a similar script here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871289/link-dropdown-list-with-htmlphpmysql/41871849#41871849    apply the same logic then u good to go

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thankyou! for the help.

Comment: let me know how it goes.